# R: Trying to create a Q-Q plot for the Weibull Distribution, getting error "NAs Introduced by Coersion"

Tags: r, weibull

I am trying to create a Q-Q plot to test if my data can be modeled by the Weibull distribution using the command

```
qqplot(x,'weibull')
```

using the data in

```
x =c(3.367, 0.769,0.8,1,1.2)
```

I keep getting presented with with the error

```
 "In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion"
```

and cannot figure out why. Does this mean I can't fit the Weibull distribution to my data? If anyone could help point me to why this isn't working, I would be very grateful.

Comment: what makes you think qqplot can be used like that? are you using something other than `stats::qqplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a `qqplot` requires some distribution to compare your data against. You'll need to establish some Weibull distribution first and then create the plot. For example:

```
x =sort(c(3.367, 0.769,0.8,1,1.2))
dist = rweibull(5, 2, 1)
qqplot(dist, x)
```

Do you have parameters for a Weibull distribution in mind? See `?rweibull` for more information, but it appears to require an n, a shape parameter, and a scale parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am able to calculate some parameters for the distribution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qualityTools` package and the `qqPlot()` function. 
If you need to estimate the parameters you can use `fitdistrplus` package.

```
   fit.weibull <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
   qqplot(qweibull(ppoints(length(x), shape = fit.weibull$estimate[1], 
           scale = fit.weibull$estimate[2]), x)
```